# Disable vim folding when autoformatting

Tags: python, vim

I'm using [`vim-autoformat/vim-autoformat`](https://github.com/vim-autoformat/vim-autoformat) to format my python code using black.

However when using the `:Autoformat` command it sometimes triggers folding. I'm not sure why but I don't want it.

The easiest example I can come with is:

```
def main():
    pass
 
a = ...
```

There needs to be an extra blank line below the `main` function.
But when I `:Autoformat` it also folds the `main` function:

```
+--  2 lines: def main():-----


a = ...
```

I don't want that behavior, if the function was not folded, why should it become folded?

However if the initial situation was with an extra blank line to remove:

```
def main():
    pass


 
a = ...
```

Then `:Autoformat` will just remove it without folding the main function:

```
def main():
    pass


a = ...
```

That last case makes more sense to me, any idea why in the first case the folding is triggered ?

Comment: Try setting `set nofoldenable`

Comment: It works only temporarily. But it made me realize that it is because of `foldlevel`. So the above case only happen if `foldlevel=0`, not if `foldlevel=1`. And this comes down to me only using `za` to toggle fold but it doesn't update the `foldlevel` and `:Autoformat` triggers updating folds according to the `foldlevel`. Seems like there is no solution?

Comment: Do you have an autocommand (or another plugin) creating views or sessions? The plugin you're using tries to restore previous views, so there could be a conflict with a view that is preserving previous folds. On the other hand, do you actually need a plugin to set `formatprg=black - -q`? Do you see the same behavior if you trigger formatting manually with gq?

Comment: @r_31415 You were right, the folding comes from [`tmhedberg/SimpylFold`](https://github.com/tmhedberg/SimpylFold), but I need it because otherwise no fold is detected. And I didn't know about `formatprg` and `gq`, but `vim-autoformat/vim-autoformat` is better since it keeps cursor position, otherwise `gggqG` to format the whole file just put the cursor at EOF.

Comment: @paime This is by design. gq{motion} follows the requested motion as it should. If you run gggqG, you're telling vim to go to the last line, so that's what it does.  For smaller motions (e.g. paragraphs), this behavior is useful when you want to repeat the same operation with ".". If you want to keep the cursor position, see h: gw, however, you cannot use `formatprg` with this option (since you're sending the entire file content to an external command and replacing the old content).

Comment: (cont) Having said that you can format the entire document and keep the same cursor position with a single line of code: `command! -buffer Fmt  let winsaved = winsaveview() | execute '%! black - -q' | call winrestview(winsaved)`  and use your regular gq{motion} for other use-cases.

Comment: I almost forgot... take a look at `set foldmethod=indent` for python files **and** change `set foldlevel` according to your needs.

Comment: @r_31415 Thanks a lot for all that information, and your `command` works like a charm! It is welcome as an answer if you want. Folding based solely on indent is 90% good for python but misses stuff like docstrings. Regarding plugins generally, I'll say I use them because they are more discoverable and often work out of the box.

Comment: @r_31415 Yes, just what I said regarding plugins, because the `Fmt` command as it is just paste the error message of `black` in my file if it can't parse the file due to some missing parentheses for example. I guess I can redirect the error to `null` and catch that to display a warning instead, but it quickly gets more involved.

Comment: I usually format my code after it runs successfully, but I understand what you're saying. In this particular case, you can still manage it rather concisely: `:command! -buffer Fmt  let winsaved = winsaveview() | execute '%! black - -q' | call winrestview(winsaved) | if
v:shell_error > 0 | silent undo | endif`. Not sure if you actually need to throw an error since you're shown the message "shell return 123" anyway. However, you can certainly add `silent execute` and add your custom error message:  `...| if v:shell_error > 0 | undo | echoerr "Error" | endif`

Comment: On the plugin issue, sure. I'm not saying you shouldn't use them. They are simply vimscript files after all, but since there is no isolation in behavior between plugins, many plugins work harmoniously until one of them gets updated and now you have a difficult to debug bug in your hands.

Comment: Amazing thank you, if I tried myself I would have gone with bash error redirection, I don't know enough vimscript.. On the other hand, now it's when it is when formatting fails that the cursor is moved and folds closed (sometimes). I can fix the moving cursor by moving the `winrestview` at the end of the command, but still folds. Anyway I can go with that.